# how to debug an abusive use of threading.lock in a multiprocess setting?

Tags: python, performance, debugging, locking, multiprocessing

I am optimizing a content pipeline and while trying multiprocessing, I had a bad surprise:  the running time doubled and, using runsnake, I realized that 90% of the time is spent on threading.lock.

I think some resource is shared accross the processes (I suspect sqlalchemy objects) and would like to check this hypothesis. But I don't see how. DO you know any way to check that ?

Comment: Are you using multiple processes, or are you using multiple threads? Or if you use both, how are you combining them?

Comment: I use pool.map from multiprocessing from a top layer in the application. There *should* be not thread beneath this layer but I can't be sure about that : part of my role here is to put the codebase back on the right track. I suspect there is at least one (hence the strange profiling) but I don't see how to determine which module use them.